# iOS: How to get streaming data from Apple music

Tags: ios, swift, audio, fft, audiounit

Now, I'm trying to make music visualization app. Is there any way to get streaming audio data from Apple music. I know Apple Music don't allow to access audio data.

My alternative solution is that playing music and record them. Using AudioUnit, I can get record data as audio streaming data.

I apologize that my English sentences are clumsy.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working with inter-app audio?